# Is there any api which would give me google search result position for keyword?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-search-platform

I was trying to find if my domain gets listed for any keywords and if so what position of which page of google search results. Is there any api available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API for what you're looking for. You could always automate that by doing the search using the browser and parsing the resulting HTML. The problem with that is the fact that Google's TOS specifically prohibits such scraping.

You could however use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/how-tos/search_analytics) Search Console API to track the top keywords for your domain and the position in the search results for that specific keyword.

Comment: Great to hear! Feel free to mark the answer as correct, if it fixed your problem.